# use different alert on user inputs

Tags: javascript

i want to show the user input on screen but **ONLY**   if its a **5 letter word** so if its less or more than 5 letters it should show an alert with something like "only 5 letter words are allowed"

and when the user uses things such as **:,/'>** and so on it should show another alert with different text. i wanted to do this with an else but this didnt work, then i used an else if but this also doesnt work as how it should be.

```
function Check_Input() {
      input = Check.value;
      if(isNaN(input)){
        for (var i=0; i<word.length; i++){
          var letter = input.charAt(i);
          document.getElementById("letter" + (i + 1) + "rij" + rownumber).innerHTML = letter;
        }
        rownumber++;
      } else {
        alert('no valid input, only letters are allowed'); 
      }
    }
    



 /*else{(input != word1.length){
      alert('only 5 letter words are allowed'); 
    }*/
```

Comment: what is Check.value? From where do you get the input?

Comment: i made an input field the input of that field is the check value

Comment: you can do basically a check if its length === 5 if yes everything is fine else do the alert

Comment: but i need 2 different alerts the problem is it doesnt do that, when i use 1 alert it works fine but when i want to add another one it doesnt work

Comment: can you share the full code and build a snippet out of it

Comment: i fixed it, i saw i missed an ( somewhere, still thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

use Reqular expression for letter validation

```
function Check_Input() {
      input = Check.value;
      let regex = /^[A-Za-z]+$/g; // regular expression for letters only
      if (regex.test(input )){ //true if text not include numbers and special characters
        if(input.length > 5){
         alert('Max 5 letters are allow')
        }else{
           // text is valid
        }
      }else{
         alert('only letters are allow')
      }
 }
```